# run c timer execute file in java

Tags: java, c

This c programme print 1 to 10 numbers in 1 second interval.This same execute c programme file(filename.out or filename.exe or ./filename) runs in java runtime, but it print 1 to 10 numbers after 10 seconds interval.I need same output format in java runtime execute,i.e it should print 1 to 10 in 1 second interval.

Advance thanks..............

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<time.h>     

#include<sys/timeb.h>

int main()

{
int i;
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
       printf("%d\n", i);
       sleep(1);
    }   
} //main
```

Java code............

```
  import java.io.*;

  import java.lang.Runtime;

  import java.lang.*;

  import java.io.File;

  public class run
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      try
      {
    String[] cmd = {"filelpath"};
    Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStream Out = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(Out);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(r);
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    {System.out.println(line);}
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Done.");
     }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }

   } //void

 } //main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly flushing out `stdout` using [`fflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

```
int main()

{
int i;
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
       printf("%d\n", i);
       sleep(1);
       fflush(stdout);
    }   
} //main
```

printf() is line-buffered by default. So newline in the printf() should flush the output immediately. But here the `stdout` is not attached to a terminal but to a java process.

Comment: Thanks i used fflush(stdout) in  c program i got the same result in java with bufferreader. without buffer reader in java it possible to get same result ?.

Comment: +1 for reminding that printf is full-buffered (and this requires fflush) for non-interactive devices.

Comment: @ma.aero The *stdout* of C program is buffered. So whether you use BufferedReader or not in java is not going to make any difference since the java program's buffering is not going to receive any input until the C program terminates.

Comment: If the c program has multiple printf statement,each printf statement required fflush(stdout) to run in java.Any other way to make simpler the program?.

Comment: @ma.aero A single `fflush(stdout)` is enough to fflush all the buffered output till that point. Alternatively, you can disable buffering using `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` before the loop so that no output is buffered.

Comment: @kingsIndian..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all output of the C program is not read until the program terminates. Perhaps it's buffered. Try reading from `r` without using `BufferedReader`.

Comment: As it turned out that the buffering occurred at C program's side, there is no point to avoid buffering at Java side.